# Stretch elements to fit a container

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm writing a form layout with this look (using Bootstrap, but I don't think that's relevant for my question):

```
+-----------------container------------------+
|                                            |
|  label1    [ input ]    label2   [ input ] |
|  label3    [ input ]    label4   [ input ] |
|  label5    [ input ]    label6   [ input ] |
|                                            |
+--------------------------------------------+
```

The `[input]` elements are fixed size. I need the two columns of labels to be correctly aligned, but I **do not** want them to be the same width. In other words, I nead the labels to expand to the widest label of that column.

Is it possible to do?

This is more or less the HTML i'm using:

```html
<div id="whatever">
<form>
  <div class="controls controls-row">
    <label for="input1">label1</label>
    <input class="span2" type="text" id="input1">
    <label for="input2">label2</label>
    <input class="span2" type="text" id="input2">
  </div>
  <div class="controls controls-row">
    <label for="input3">label3</label>
    <input class="span2" type="text" id="input3">
    <label for="input4">label4</label>
    <input class="span4" type="text" id="input4">
  </div>
</form>
</div>
```

Comment: Hm, you could do it by having the elements arranged in columns (instead of rows), and then floating the columns, and right-aligning the inputs, while ensuring that the labels are not broken into multiple lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

display: table, and table-cell could work.

column is also an option, but less compatible. (@Sirko shown a great demo.)

css

```
form {
    display:table;
}

.controls-row {
    display: table-row;
}

.controls-row > label,
.controls-row > input {
    display: table-cell;
}
```

jsFiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Mxx4M/

Answer (score 1):

You could try [`column-count`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/CSS/column-count) ([browser-compatibility](http://caniuse.com/#feat=multicolumn)). Your HTML would have to change to something like this:

```
<div id="whatever">
<form>
  <div class="controls controls-row">
    <label for="input1">label1</label>
    <input class="span2" type="text" id="input1">
  </div>
  <div class="controls controls-row">
    <label for="input2">label2</label>
    <input class="span2" type="text" id="input2">
  </div>
  <div class="controls controls-row">
    <label for="input3">label3</label>
    <input class="span2" type="text" id="input3">
  </div>
  <div class="controls controls-row">
    <label for="input4">label4</label>
    <input class="span4" type="text" id="input4">
  </div>
</form>
</div>
```

and then apply the following CSS:

```
#whatever { 
  -moz-column-count: 2; 
  -webkit-column-count: 2; 
  column-count: 2; 
}
.controls-row { white-space: nowrap; }
```

The second CSS-rule prevents line-breaks within a input-label row.

Comment: The non-prefixed version of a property should *always* be listed *after* the prefixed versions.  It should also be noted that the order of the elements will differ from what the OP presented in his sample layout:  the first column will contain elements 1-3, the second will contain 4-6.

Comment: @cimmanon As to the ordering of properties: Noted and changed - thanks. As to the other point: this only gives a rough idea, how to solve OPs problem. Most likely the order of elements can be adjusted by the generating script.

Comment: +1 for showing the column-count property, that I didn't know, but I need IE9 compatibility. It's a pitty, but....